# How to insert, update and delete the attributes in xml contained within a clob in oracle DB using Active Record?

Tags: ruby, xml, oracle, activerecord

I am able to update/insert/delete the attributes in xml contained within a CLOB (more than 4000 char) in oracle database using available oracle xml type operations (updatexml(), deleteXml(), appendChildXml(), insertChildXml(), or insertXmlBefore(), etc.). But I need to implement the same using Active Record in my automation.

How should we handle this in Active Record?

Thanks in advance,
Anto